# Unix Domain Sockets, Udp Sockets Objective C what to use?

Tags: c++, cocoa, sockets, synchronization, udp

I'm writing an interactive editing video application that uses Quartz Composer as a real time video processor. Time and synchronization are very important in my application.

My first application coded in C++ must send commands like "play" at this "path" "this file video" "start" at this "time" "stop", etc. For this udp sockets work just fine
.
 I use one socket for each command so the order of command never messed-up, such thing will be fatal!

The real issue is when my Quartz Composer Patch start to send the current time to my second application that will control the bar of my timeline so the user  have a graphics representation of the actual advance of the video there Udp sockets are just not enough fast and send packets in different order or duplications.

I though that unix socket domain could help me but when I looked  all the examples that I found in the web where writed in C and not in objC and the pluguins for Quartz Composer can only be coded in objC I know I could wrap the C code myself but before start this herculean task how to be sure that Unix socket is what I need?

Are really Unix socket fast and reliable enough for what I’m trying to do?

Is there another way that you know for synchronize process in objC I have look pipes, shared memory but it is not clear to me how to implement this in my plug-in.

Comment: By "I use one socket for each command", do you mean you open a new socket every time? And you're using UDP for local (single-machine) IPC? And you're wondering if Unix domain sockets are fast enough?

Comment: Yes i'm using UDP for Local machine i'm wondering if Unix domain sockets are faster enough to send for example 25/s or 30/s updates to my GUI in the other application UDP just gets stuck... Yes i use a sockets for each command that i send to the video application one for saying play one for saying stop one for set the start time of the video etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes i'm using UDP for Local machine
>   i'm wondering if Unix domain sockets
>   are faster enough to send for example
>   25/s or 30/s updates to my GUI in the
>   other application UDP just gets
>   stuck...

Unix sockets might be a little faster, and probably more importantly they provide reliable delivery (unlike UDP).  But your comment about speed, and the idea that UDP as a protocol is preventing you from posting 30 updates per second to a GUI makes me think that the problem is not in the choice of protocol at all, but somewhere else.  In other words, I think Unix sockets will be faster than UDP, but I doubt they will solve your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer john
You are right I expressed vaguely in my last message. What I meant to say is that I’m using Udp Sockets to synchronize my GUI with a process from another application and knowing the reliability issues with this protocol I will like to use Unix Domain Sockets instead. 
One problem is that the examples that I have found like the CFLocalServer from apple are write in C and the applications that I’m using only let use Objective-C for coding the plug-in, how can I create Unix-sockets in objective-c?

Comment: In this case I would urge you to use TCP for now.  It should be a very easy transition from UDP, with plenty of good documentation and support to guide you.  Unix sockets may become necessary in the future, but having migrated from UDP to TCP will only serve to prepare you for that transition should it prove necessary.  But frankly, I suspect TCP will solve the reliability issues you have seen with UDP without harming your product at all.  I say keep it simple, at least until simple turns out not to be good enough.